# How can I use my TopComponent as a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, rcp, netbeans-platform

Netbeans Platform's TopComponents are functionally similar to JFrames in many ways, and are intended to be used so, besides the fact that [`TopComponent`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-windows/org/openide/windows/TopComponent.html) extends `JComponent`.

However, I'm currently trying to use [Docking Frames](http://dock.javaforge.com/index.html) for my application. I would like to insert a bunch of these in one of my TopComponents, but the control class expects a JFrame as a parameter, and it cannot be instantiated without it. As I said, `TopComponent` doesn't extend `JFrame`, so I can't simply cast them, but sadly, they would *probably* do the trick if I could.

What can I do?

Comment: A bit obvious, but why can't you just use JFrames instead of TopComponents?

Comment: @CanadianDavid I wish I could, but someone decided that we must play by Netbeans Platform's rules. Design decision. Therefore, as their name suggest, we use TopComponents as top containers instead of a JFrame. Is there another way? That's part of the question.

Comment: An [`org.openide.windows.TopComponent`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-windows/org/openide/windows/TopComponent.html) "may be docked or undocked." Why do you need Docking Frames?

Comment: @trashgod I need docked panels inside my docked TopComponents. AFAIK we can't nest TopComponents (hence the name) so I needed another tool (and Docking Frames seems perfect). It might look confusing, but that's what the users want.

Answer (score 0):

Try using nested `JPanel` instead.

1. Click on "Design" and right mouse button click and change layout from "Free" to `GridBagLayout`.
2. Add inner `JPanel`. I use `GridBagConstraints` because it's just one line method to ensure "full frame" layout. You can probably use any other layout to do the same.

I try to keep `TopComponent` as small as possible. All GUI components are in nested `JPanels`. When you want to test your code without NetBeans platform you'd just add parent `JFrame` instead of `TopComponent`.

```
public MyTopComponent() {
   initComponents();
   panel = new MyPanel();
   //ensures that our panel will be using 100% of our TopComponent
   add(panel, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0,
       GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST, 
       GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
       new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0)
   );
}

//this code is generated by GUI editor
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {   
    setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());
}// </editor-fold>
```